# try catch exeptions using mariadb

Tags: python, exception, mariadb

I want to insert values on mariadb tables. i want to add try except exception to get the values of the rows that caused the error to handle the error?

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (id varchar(36) primary key, n1 VARCHAR(4), n2 varchar(55), n3 int(6), Version VARCHAR(4));")
id = uuid.uuid1()
id = str(id)
# try
cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO t2 (id, n1, n2, n3, Version) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s )", (vals))
  #except
```

Comment: So add the exception. What are you asking, specifically? The brackets around `vals` don't do anything, btw, and you haven't shown an example of the data

Comment: how can i do to get the values of this row? @roganjosh its my first time to handle exception. thank you

Comment: What is the exception you're expecting? Run it without the try/except and pay attention to the trace back. That will give you virtually all the info you'll need to identify where the custom exception is defined and should be imported from

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html?highlight=exceptions

Comment: You can just let the command run with nonsensical values. In the error traceback it will say what error was raised. You can catch that error explicitely. (Or catch all errors but you shouldn't do that.) In the execept block you do a simple `print(vals)` and then you can see the values that caused the error.

Comment: @TinNguyen i didn't understant what do you mean please?

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pattern you may follow:

```
import mysql.connector

cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t1 (id varchar(36) primary key, n1 VARCHAR(4), n2 varchar(55), n3 int(6), Version VARCHAR(4));")
id = uuid.uuid1()
id = str(id)
fail_ids = []
try:
    cursor.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO t2 (id, n1, n2, n3, Version) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s )", (vals))
except mariadb.Error as err:
    print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
    fail_ids.append(vals[0])
```

But in general, you should have a good handle on the data you are trying to insert.  Your Python script is not the place to be cleaning/scrubbing your data.

I have also given you an option to maintain a list of failing `id` values, which you may use later on to identify the offending rows.

Comment: I was able to add generate a message of the error. But What i want is get a list of this row (the row causing the problem). Please tell me if im not clear in my explanation. Thank you

Comment: You've lost me on "Your Python script is not the place to be cleaning/scrubbing your data." in the edit. Are you referring to this _specific_ script? Otherwise, I'd argue that python, in general, is perfect for the job

Comment: What I am saying is that you try to ensure that when you take your script to production, there are no data issues such as this one.  If you want to populate a list with rows, just do that.